# Ajuda em função com ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, funções

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse código ?                                           não está funcionando, não consigo achar o erro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int chamar(int *n){

        printf("Digite o valor de n:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        printf("%d",n);
        return 0;

        }

int main(void){

        int n;
        chamar(n);
        printf("\n%d\n",n);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir o valor na variável `n` dentro do `main`, vc precisa passar o endereço de memória dela, e você faz isso igual no `scanf`:

```
chamar(&n);
```

e no método chamar, como o parâmetro já é um ponteiro, você não precisa passar o endereço de memória dele, assim ficando:

```
int chamar(int *n){
    printf("Digite o valor de n:");
    scanf("%d",n);
    printf("%d",*n);

    return 0;
}
```

Percebe-se que o `n` do `printf` dento de `chamar` possui um `*`, o `*` serve para criar um ponteiro e para pegar o valor de dentro do ponteiro, e o `&` serve para pegar o endereço de memória da variável.